# How does (r-1) complement for subtraction work?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, decimal-expansion

My instructor gave an algorithm for doing subtraction with (r-1)'s complement. For subtracting M - N, it goes like the following.

1. Find the (r-1)'s complement of N by using formula r^n - r^-m - N. n is the number of non-fractionated digits and the m represent the number of digits after the radix point. For instance, if N = 324.16 in decimal, the formula would 10^3 - 10^-2 - 324.16
2. Next, Add the M to N's complement. If there is an end around carry, add it to the least significant digit. Else, take the r-1's complement of the sum.

The algorithm works but I just don't understand how it works. Can someone explain ?

Comment: Hint: $m-n=m+(-n)$.

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate M-N

1. First, we add (r-1)'s complement of second number in the first number: M+(r^n-r^-m-N).
2. Then take r-1's complement of number: r^n-r^-m-[M+(r^n-r^-m-N)]=r^n-r^-m-M-r^n+r^-m+N=-M+N
3. lastly, put a -ve sign in front: -(-M+N)=M-N

Actually the process is same whether we subtract larger number from smaller one or vice versa. But, this two are often considered as separate cases, simplifying calculation

case-1: M>N.
Here, addition of M and (r-1)'s complement of N will give a carry. The trick is to add this carry to LSB. This trick is just to make remembering (r-1)'s complement subtraction easier. But, what we are actually doing is discarding this carry and add a separate 1 to the answer. Carry was appeared due to 2^n part while taking complement. So, we are simply discarding that 1 extra bit which was caused by addition of r^n. We are adding one to the answer in order to compensate the reduction caused due to r^-m part.

case-2: M<N
Here the trick won't work. Because there won't be carry. So, we realize that we actually subtracted larger number from a smaller one and only way to get result is now following the standard steps mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

subtraction using complement is something like comparing two values indirectly using some standard third value(r's or r-1's complement). suppose there are two straight lines on paper and we want to fined difference in length between them then we draw third line greater then both of previous lines and compare both of these lines with third one and then easily find difference between them without comparing them directly.